# Using shoutcast jquery, get album art from lastfm

Tags: jquery, shoutcast, last.fm

Using the wavestreaming jquery plugin ( https://github.com/Wavestreaming/jquery-shoutcast ) i can get song info form my server for now playing

```
$.SHOUTcast({
   host : 'stardust.wavestreamer.com',
   port : 8062,
   interval : 5000,
   stats : function(){
      $('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle'));
   }
}).startStats();
```

and recently played.

```
$.SHOUTcast({
   host : 'stardust.wavestreamer.com',
   port : 8062,
   playedInterval : 20000,
   played : function(tracks){
      $('ul').html('');
      $.each(tracks,function(k,track){
         $('ul').append('<li>'+track.title+'</li>');
          ));
   }
}).startPlayed();
```

How can i integrate Last FM track.getinfo JSON response

```
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&track=(trackname)&artist=(artist)&user='+settings.username+'&api_key='+settings.apikey+'+'&format=json&callback=?
```

to display album art in img tag if there's one and if there's not, display a default artwork?